# How to use clang with Visual Studio and stlib？

Tags: visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2015, clang++, llvm-clang

I have installed prebuilt llvm + clang for windows 3.6.2, and Visual Studio 2015. Now in VS 2015, you can create projects and set compiler to clang. It seems the installation of clang has registered the compilers to the settings. Everything else works fine, except I cannot use and standard libraries.

The compiler setting for clang is LLVM-vs2014 under properties->general->platform tools

For instance, when compiling this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    return 0; }
```

if I delete the #include  line, everything works fine.

any idea?

```
The output message from VS is:
1>------ Build started: Project: TT, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/ZI'

1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gm'

1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/GS'

1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/fp:precise'

1>clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/FdDebug\vc140.pdb'

1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:

1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:

1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:

1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:

1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:

1

>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:7:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cmath:656:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtgmath.h:8:

    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtr1common(231,22): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'

    1>          struct _Is_integral<char16_t>

    1>                              ^
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xtr1common(237,22): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'

    1>          struct _Is_integral<char32_t>

    1>                              ^
    1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:10:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\streambuf:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xiosbase:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale:8:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdexcept:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception:7:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits:6:

    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstddef(408,14): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'

    1>          struct hash<char16_t>

    1>                      ^

    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstddef(414,14): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'

    1>          struct hash<char32_t>

    1>                      ^
    1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:10:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\streambuf:6:

        1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xiosbase:6:

        1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale:8:

    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdexcept:7:
    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring:6:
    1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0:8:
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\limits(615,33): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
    1>  template<> class numeric_limits<char16_t>

1>                                  ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\limits(905,33): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
1>  template<> class numeric_limits<char32_t>
1>                                  ^
1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:10:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\streambuf:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xiosbase:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale:8:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdexcept:7:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0:10:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility:8:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility:7:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iosfwd(267,21): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
1>          struct char_traits<char16_t>
1>                             ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iosfwd(276,21): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
1>          struct char_traits<char32_t>
1>                             ^
1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:10:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\streambuf:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xiosbase:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale:8:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdexcept:7:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring(2623,22): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
1>  typedef basic_string<char16_t, char_traits<char16_t>, allocator<char16_t> >
1>                       ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring(2623,53): error : expected unqualified-id
1>  typedef basic_string<char16_t, char_traits<char16_t>, allocator<char16_t> >
1>                                                      ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring(2625,22): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
1>  typedef basic_string<char32_t, char_traits<char32_t>, allocator<char32_t> >
1>                       ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstring(2625,53): error : expected unqualified-id
1>  typedef basic_string<char32_t, char_traits<char32_t>, allocator<char32_t> >
1>                                                      ^
1>  In file included from main.cpp:1:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:10:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\streambuf:6:
1>  In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xiosbase:6:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale(1004,30): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
1>          class _CRTIMP2_PURE codecvt<char16_t, char, _Mbstatet>
1>                                      ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocale(1328,30): error : use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
1>          class _CRTIMP2_PURE codecvt<char32_t, char, _Mbstatet>
1>                                      ^
1>  14 errors generated.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I just installed clang prebuild package from llvm.org. And VS 2015. Although I have had mingw and cygwin g++, gcc installed before this.

Comment: The error message is:

Comment: I have added the output from VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang 3.6 doesn't support the C++11 keywords `char16_t` and `char32_t` in Microsoft mode ([see the source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_36/include/clang/Basic/TokenKinds.def#L334-L335)). However good news, 3.7 does and will be released in three weeks (August 21) according to the LLVM website. In the meanwhile you could install a [3.7 release candidate](http://llvm.org/pre-releases/3.7.0/) or a [snapshot build](http://llvm.org/builds/).

Comment: This is awesome, version 3.7 plays well with VS, even debugging! Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work for me. In 3.9. They seem to have broken the support for char16_t and char32_t.

Comment: @rxantos: It still does for me (VS2015 Upd. 1 + LLVM-3.9.0-r263536-win32.exe + LLVM-vs2014 toolset). Without any more details I can't really say why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @rxantos. It requires the `-fms-compatibility-version=19` flag; https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24231#c1